# Combinatorics: Three letters are to be selected from the letters in the word questions...

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How do I solve the following questions?

1. a) Three letters are to be selected from the letters in the word CONSTANT. How many different combinations are there?

b) Three letters are to be selected from the letters in the word JUGGLING. How many different combinations are there?

Just some questions I have come across preparing for a test.

I have attempted to list the individual letter cases and how many different ways there are of choosing the three (i.e. Choose 3 different letters for CONSTANT or two identical from CONSTANT), however, I would like clarification on this technique to make sure my method is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct. You are basically making a case for each way to get three letters, and then adding all of these individual cases together. Number of letters in CONSTANT is 6

Hence, number of 3 letter words is $${6 \choose 3}.3! + {2 \choose 1}.{5 \choose 1}.3$$

Comment: So the answer is 150? Isn't there more than 2 cases?

Comment: The second term is when a letter is repeated. There are two options for that - N,T. For the remaining letter, there are now 5 options, and the number of permutations is 3 of this word